# How to use users input continue with file in directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

My code is:

```
print("I have found the following files:")

initial_count = 0
direc = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/GIT/python_adb/apks/')

for file in os.listdir(direc):
    initial_count += 1
    files = print('[', initial_count, ']' , file)
    files
```

And my output:

```
I have found the following files:
[ 1 ] Kik.apk
[ 2 ] vlc_for_android.apk
```

Now I want to ask the user which file he wants to use, like:

```
apk_choice = input("Which apk do yo want to install? Type in the number of the file like 1 or 2 and press enter.")
```

How can I use the users input, e.g. he typed in 1 and pressed enter, to go with [ 1 ] Kik.apk?

So how to compare his input with the files and continue with the chosen file?

Comment: chooesen_path = os.path.join(direc, file)?

Comment: Save the files to a list: `files = os.listdir(direc)` and then access the list with the user's choice (-1 because lists are 0-based): `files[apk_choice-1]`

Comment: @Tomerikoo this is what I get: `Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: Because your input is a string. You need to do `files[int(apk_choice)-1]`

Comment: @Tomerikoo `Exception has occurred: TypeError
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
  File "/home/frxhb/Documents/GIT/python_adb/user_choice_test.py", line 103, in <module>
    files[int(apk_choice)-1]`

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: If you are actually doing `files = print(...)` that's absolutely wrong. `print` has no return value, it only....... prints...

Comment: @Tomerikoo unfortunately I cant use http://www.pythontutor.com/ because in this u cant import os

Comment: I assume you didn't read the link about debugging. You don't need PythonTutor to debug your code. Simply adding prints helps sometimes. If you did `print(files)` you'll see that it's `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a list of the files and the given number as an index:

```
print("I have found the following files:")

initial_count = 0
direc = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/GIT/python_adb/apks/')
files = os.listdir(direc)

for file in files:
    initial_count += 1
    print('[', initial_count, ']' , file)

inp = input(">>>")
print(files[int(inp)-1])
```

Note: You have to subtract 1 from the input because lists in Python are 0-based indexing.

Comment: Note that it is not necessary to maintain a variable for the count. You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead: `for index, file in enumerate(files, 1):`

Comment: I get the following error code when I type in 1 or 2 in input and press enter: `Exception has occurred: TypeError
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Can you please try and print out the files array?

Comment: @Wrench56 Ok let me check my code once again cause I got now nearly what I want. My output: `I have found the following files:
[ 1 ] Kik.apk
[ 2 ] vlc_for_android.apk
>>>1
Kik.apk`

Comment: oh you have to only enter 1 without the string "Kik.apk" (Or just bad formatting?)

Comment: I did enter "1". >>>1 (thats my input). Then `Kik.apk` came out

Comment: well is that the solution? Or is there something else you need? (Because the output looks convincing) If no, please close the thread by accepting the right solution.

Comment: Yes the output looks very good.  My next little question: I added following: `apk_choice = files[int(inp)-1]` . When the output is "kik.apk" , how can I add this to this: `joint_path = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/GIT/python_adb/apks/->apk_choice<-')` ? Like how can I add this to the path variable ?

Comment: you could do something like ``path = '~/Documents/GIT/python_adb/apks/'`` and then ``print(path + str(files[int(apk_choice)-1]))`` Or just use os.path.join (tho i dont know if it would work with this path)

Comment: @Wrench56 thanks dude I got it. I used: `joint_path = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/GIT/python_adb/apks/' +apk_choice)` and when I print it, I get: `/home/frxhb/Documents/GIT/python_adb/apks/Kik.apk`

Comment: Nice! Glad you got it :)